# Argument Error thrown when using SciPy's ODR

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, curve-fitting

I am using SciPy's ODR routine to find the best correlations to statistical data.  I've used curve_fit from scipy.optimize in the past, but in this case both the independent and dependent variables have errors associated with them, and I've been told to use ODR in this case.

However, when I run the routine, I get an error thrown.  Here is a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.odr import ODR, Model, RealData

# Define a linear function to fit.
def linear_func(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

# Create an array to feed into the linear function to create test data.
x_array = np.linspace(0, 5, 6)

# Create a y array of data.
y_array = linear_func(x_array, 2, 0.5)

# Define the data being fit.
data = RealData(x_array, y_array)

# Define the model being fit.
model = Model(linear_func)

# Define the ODR that will be used to fit the data.
odr = ODR(data, model, beta0=[1, 1])
odr.set_job(fit_type=2)

# Run the model.
fit = odr.run()
```

Running this code produces the following error which is identical to the one I receive when I run my program in full:

```
TypeError: linear_func() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I assume this is taking issue with the line beta0=[1, 1], but changing this to beta0=[1, 1, 1] still gives the same error, and indeed so does beta0=[].  There are only two variables in the linear function anyway, a and b, so that's another point of confusion.  This setup worked fine with curve_fit, so I'm at a loss to explain why I'm getting the error here.

Comment: You get this as the values are send as list. check the documentation how to handle this. see e.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scipy/scipy_odr.htm

Comment: Yes, I saw that on the documentation, but I assumed that it would work both ways because the way I did it works for curve_fit and is more intuitively obvious.  How do I get it to work that way?  The documented way is rather opaque for my liking.

Comment: You would pass something like `params` and then resolve in your function as ` a, b = params`.